# Trying to cast molted table to very wide table gives error: "Cross product ... would result in xyz rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max..."

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to transform my data by applying one hot encoding to some of my columns. I am using data.table's melt and dcast to get there. For small datasets this works. But it breaks on the entire datasets while handling the call to `dcast` with the following error:

```
Error in CJ(1:1992389, 1:3228) :
  Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 6431431692 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647
Calls: create.and.insert.into.table.psms_wide.2 -> dcast -> dcast.data.table -> do.call -> CJ
Execution halted
```

Apparently I am hitting some integral limit in one of the internal operations. My code looks like this.

```
library(data.table)

# record count is 4668480
load(paste0(dat.root,'MY_DATA.RData'));

df <- MY_DATA
setDT(df)

#Make sure that the to-be-pivotted columns are of factor type.
df$X = as.factor(df$X)
df$Y = as.factor(df$Y)

# Make sure that X and Y have the same level set so that melt won't complain.
all_levels <- union(levels(df$X), levels(df$Y))
df$X   = factor(df$X, levels = all_levels)
df$Y = factor(df$Y, levels = all_levels)

# transforming regular table to the 'melted' form
# non_measure_column_1,..., non_measure_column_N, measure, value
#===============================================================
# non_measure_value_11, ..., non_measure_value_1N, X   , some_X_value
# non_measure_value_21, ..., non_measure_value_2N, Y , some_Y_value
# non_measure_value_31, ..., non_measure_value_3N, X   , some_other_X_value
# ...
df <- melt(df, measure.vars = c("X", "Y"),  value.factor=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)

# now transform the melted form to the wide one-hot encoded form:
# non_measure_column_1,..., non_measure_column_N  , X_some_X_value, Y_some_Y_value, X_some_other_X_value, ...
# non_measure_value_11, ..., non_measure_value_1N , 1                   , 0                       , 0
# non_measure_value_21, ..., non_measure_value_2N , 0                   , 1                       , 0
# non_measure_value_31, ..., non_measure_value_3N , 0                   , 0                       , 1
df <- dcast(df, ... ~ variable + value, fun = length)
```

I realize that my expected result is both very wide and very tall. For system resource limits I already had to shift from `data.frame`'s to `data.table`'s and from `reshape2` to `data.table` methods. So far I managed to get my code to work if I take on subsets of my data smaller then a million rows.

What do I need to do to make this work given the R restrictions?
Chunkwise tall-to-wide + union of intermediate results?

Comment: This seems to be only a subpart of longer data munging process. A wild guess is that you might be better of when your subsequent data processing steps are working with the data in  long format. With as large datasets as yours, you may find it worthwhile to take advantage of the speed-up by using the data.table syntax. See the introductory material [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I definitely need the wide format and I AM using `data.table`'s, i.e. I am calling `setDT`. And this is basically the entire data munging process. After the last statement of the code snippet I would have called `dbWriteTable()`. I have verified that the original serialized data.frame can be imported into a database. The only weird thing about my data is that column X contains values with new line character and arithmetic characters, e.g. '+' sign. Hence after pivoting I could end up with data.table columns containing a new line character.